# Errors using Wubi on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, wubi, installation

I tried to install Ubuntu on my Windows 7 64-bit PC and encountered multiple error screens.  It finally showed an error with `users\appdata\local\temp\wubi-11.10-rev245.log`.

Comment: Please open that `.log` file and post its entire contents at http://paste.ubuntu.com, then edit your question to add a link to it.

Comment: how secure would that be

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? As for your question about security with paste.ubuntu.com, its secure enough for your logs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without the log file it's not possible to identify the exact cause of the problem.

However, the easiest way to install Wubi is to download wubi.exe and the desktop CD ISO yourself and save them both in the same directory on your harddrive.
e.g. the [11.10 64-bit desktop CD ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso) and the [11.10 wubi.exe](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/wubi.exe)

Then remove all Ubuntu USB and CDs from the computer (any ISO on the root of a drive e.g. E:\ as well). This is important. Now run that wubi.exe

Some software will associate itself with the .iso extension and identify the ISO as an archive or offer to do some default action. Just select to save the ISO. Or right click on the link and select "Save link as" to bypass the software. If you go direct to http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ there are other download options e.g. the .torrent extension which will open up in your bit torrent client. It doesn't matter where you save the ISO as long as it's in the same place as the wubi.exe of the same release.

Comment: when I click the link to get the ISO a window pops up and asks       What should Firefox do with this file?  Open With......

Answer (score -1):

Did you try Wubi straight from the Ubuntu website AND make sure to pick an installation of ***above*** 15 gig? The Wubi installer has a little bit of difficulty determining bit versions, and while not normally a problem for 64 bit computers the "program" nature of Wubi doesnt always work well running 32 on a 64 bit machine. Otherwise anytime I've encountered that error (usually from XP however) i fixed it running a live USB (instead of live CD) and installing via the icon in the live USB system.

Hope this helps bro.

Comment: Yeah it's helping. I chose the 64 bit version and the installation size is 18 gig.  How do I use a live USB?

Comment: @keith You should only follow Riley Sikora's instructions for installing from a live USB if you do **not** want a Wubi system. Do you want a Wubi system, or do you want a fully fledged Ubuntu system installed with its own partitions, alongside (but not inside) your Windows system? (You may want to read up on the differences.)

Comment: I'm not sure really.  I just want to try it from my usb to see how it works.  I downloaded the universal usb installer that ubuntu recommended, but when I click browse to find the .iso file it's not where it shows in the diagram

Comment: The wubi installer does not have a problem determining the computer architecture (32bit or 64bit). I haven't seen a single case where it gets it wrong - please point to an example if you know. There is also no problem running 32bit Ubuntu on a 64bit machine. You also do not need 15Gigabyte for an install. 5GB (the minimum on release 11.10) works fine.

Comment: When I try the Wubi installer I get an error screen

Comment: It says     There is no disk in the drive.  Please insert a disk into drive\Device\Harddisk2\DR@

Comment: When I try to download the .iso where do I download it too?  In the pictures it has it on the desktop but my dialogue box brings up Nero

Comment: I also have cable internet with between 6-10meg speed but the .iso is only downloading at under 100kbs

Comment: The no disk in the drive message: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/365881 ; For downloading, you can use a bittorrent client - it's usually faster.

Comment: I read the posts in the link but none of them helped me figure out my problem.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: One post mentioned to disable all drives usb and unused optical drives.  How would I do that?